# javafx Combobox<Integer> type mismatch

Tags: java, javafx-2

my problem is as follows:

```
class xxx {
@FXML
private Combobox<Integer> cmb_year;
...
public void method ()
{
 int year=2013;
 cmb_year.getItems().add(year);
 cmb_year.setValue(year) ---> argumenttype mismatch
}
}
```

It's fragments of my code, but shows the problem I encounter.

I've tried with

- making "int year" to "Integer year"
- Accessing overcmb_year.getSelectionModel().select(new Integer(year))
- Accessing over cmb_year.getSelectionModel().select(year)

Always leads to an argumenttype mismatch.

What can cause this?

Comment: Is it a runtime or a compile error?

Comment: runtime, not even a warning at compiletime

Comment: Do you use a `StringConverter`?

Comment: This question is mistagged.  It is a question about JavaFX 2+, and not JavaFX 1.3.

Comment: setValue attempts to copy the specified item from the list of cells into the button cell (or just put it in the button cell if it's not in the list).  Have you set the button cell?  I suspect that the mismatch occurs because the button cell is not a ListCell<Integer>.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set which item is selected, you want to work with the ComboBox's SelectionModel:

```
cmb_year.getSelectionModel().select(cmb_year.getItems().indexOf(year));
```

You could also try `setSelectedItem(year)` or `selectLast()`.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the ComboBox API will automatically set the selected item to the value specified in setValue() if it happens to already be in the ComboBox's list view.

Answer (score 0):

This may simply be an issue with the ComboBox not being initialized properly or completely.  I never use ComboBoxes "out of the box".  I use several lines of code to set them up.

Following is a code excerpt from the initialize() method in one of my dialog controller classes (this ComboBox displays a list of Institution objects):

```
    // this first line gets the data from my data source
    // the ComboBox is referenced by the variable 'cbxInst'

    ObservableList<Institution> ilist = Institution.getInstitutionList(); 
    Callback<ListView<Institution>, ListCell<Institution>> cellfactory =
            new Callback<ListView<Institution>, ListCell<Institution>>() {
                @Override
                public ListCell<Institution> call(ListView<Institution> p) {
                    return new InstitutionListCell();
                }
            };

    cbxInst.setCellFactory(cellfactory);
    cbxInst.setButtonCell(cellfactory.call(null));
    cbxInst.setItems(ilist);
```

The key points here are:

- I define a cell factory to generate ListCell instances for the ComboBox to display.
- I use the factory to create a ListCell instance to initialize the Button Cell with.

For completeness, here is the private member class from which the Institution ListCell instances are created:

```
private final class InstitutionListCell extends ListCell<Institution> {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Institution item, boolean empty){
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (item != null) {                
            this.setText(item.getName());

        } else {
            this.setText(Census.FORMAT_TEXT_NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

If you were to initialize your ComboBox in a similar way, it may be that your problems will be solved.